# can I process UIImage in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage

I want to process the UIImage bit by bit. As per the attached example first is normal image and the second one is processed image with CGBitmapContextCreate function.

Any ideas or reference guys ?

I have little idea about, through which it can be achieved but not sure how can we process bit by bit.[image]

```
CGContextRef context;
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData,
                                CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage),
                                8,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace(sourceImage),
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

[image]

Comment: I've whipped up a basic image editor category for UIImage, from which you can do edits and transforms on any image. See it here: http://github.com/H2CO3/UIImage-Editor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process images, you have different technologies :

- check Core Image to see what filters are built-in and how to apply them to images. Note that Core Image is also available on Mac OS, and you can build custom filters
- for more "image processing" or "computer vision" related tasks (I'm talking of the technical fields here, not pimping images), you need to gain access to the bitmap data of images. For this, you an create a CGImage from a UIImage (see Quartz documentation), or if you're grabbing from a webcam you'll want to use an intermediate buffer (see the AVFoundation frmework).

Comment: Quartz core is slower than the OpenGL. if you want fast image processing then you should go for open GL.

Comment: Not really: Quartz also relies on an OpenGL backend. Quartz is the framework for drawings, hence including creating/fetching bitmaps, and as such you can't get image data without using this framework.

Comment: but when i made an app for converting an image to drawing i applied processor of iphone took 3 min for a 1000x1000 pxl image with quartzcore. and same with the help of OpenGL took only 1 sec.

Comment: OpenGL ES is indeed far faster than using CPU-bound processing. Quartz does not use OpenGL ES for rasterization on iOS, and for an operation like this you'd generally be iterating through pixels using a CPU-based operation. In my experience, this can run anywhere from 2X-180X slower than a shader-based implementation using OpenGL ES. Also the phrase "you can build custom filters" does not apply to Core Image on iOS.